# How to filter already filtered value in twig? Filters: replace, title, raw in the same expression

Tags: twig

I need to use filter `|title` to the below outcome:

`{{ sentence|lower|replace({(word): '<span style="font-weight: bold;">'~word~'</span>'})|raw }}`

how to do that?

---

edit:

I'm trying:

```
{% autoescape false %}
{% set foo %}
    {{ sentence|lower|replace({(word): '<span style="font-weight: bold;">'~word~'</span>'})|raw }}
{% endset %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

then:

```
{{ foo|title }}
```

but it results below in source code:

`&lt;Span Style=&quot;font-Weight: Bold;&quot;&gt;Emily&lt;/span&gt; Dickinson`

and render on the screen:

```
<Span Style="font-Weight: Bold;">Emily</span> Dickinson
```

Comment: Have you tried `{{ foo|title|raw }}`? I think `raw` only has effect when it is being printed out.

Comment: yes, you're right. I dont even need to set variable (`{% set foo %}`). Just put `|title` filter before `|raw ` does the trick. But if i want to `{% set foo %}` i need to write `{% autoescape false %}` without `|raw` and then `{{ foo|title|raw }}` as you said. If you want, write an answer i will accept that.

Comment: anyway it's all waste of time for highlight searched word. For searched word "william" it results "William Carlos WilliamS" with big "S" at the end. CSS `text-transform:capitalize;` instead of filter `|title` do the trick. But its not an issue of top question.

Comment: If you created the filter `title` yourself you can remove the extra filter `raw` by returning a [Twig_Markup](http://pastebin.com/w3QPRGkA)

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks. (Is there a typo? Shouldn't be: `preg_quote($needles)` instead of: `preg_quote($needle)`?)

Comment: Its seems my `$needles` array is obsolete as I use the `i` (case insensitive) modifer :-)